# Referring to another workbook in Excel Online

Tags: excel-online

I'm trying to do a COUNTIF in Excel Online that counts the number of times a word appears in another workbook in Excel Online. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work the same way in Excel Online as it does in Excel.

Anyone know if this is even possible?